# Till when is it OK to ask "How are you?" in an e-mail?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

In an e-mail to close colleagues, I would like to ask "How are you doing today?" in the beginning part. But till when is it natural to begin in this way? For example, I need to report one minor thing to a close colleague at 6PM as a first contact during the day. Can I ask this though it is already 6PM? I would like to say something to imply I care you personally, and to imply my interest is not only business with you. Is there any better expression? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined not to phrase it as a question, but rather something like:

> '[I] hope you are doing well'

or

> '[I] hope your day is going well'.

This seems a little less awkward and a little more natural in an email context.

As for the **6PM** dilemma, I think you're right that it might be better to say something like 'I hope your day **has gone** well' instead of the second suggestion above. However, 'I hope you're doing well' will work at any time.